# SQL statements with SQL Server . please

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

Why not 2 rows. and how to ...  Please!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Rancho Take 2 minutes from your busy day and tell us what is your question.

Comment: only partition by sex, but other column also takes effect.

Comment: First, try tell us exactly what you want your query to do.

Comment: *Why not 2 rows. and how to ... Please!* I think you accidently the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have it right. All rows are appearing, but because of your "partition" clause, the "0" sex is appearing before the '1' sex, so the records "appear" out of order by the ID.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this, this will give your desired result, what I u want as per your comment below question.

```
SELECT id, name, age from [User_Info] g
WHERE age IN
(
SELECT max(age) as MaxF_age FROM [User_Info]
WHERE  sex=1
UNION  All
SELECT max(age) as MaxM_age FROM [User_Info]
WHERE  sex=0
)
```